# alsa crash with " ALSA sound/usb/urb.c:179 cannot submit urb (err = -27)" on imx6q sabrelite

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, kernel, alsa

I am using alsa pcm player to listen to audio. The alsa pcm crashes with the error:  ALSA sound/usb/urb.c:179 cannot submit urb (err = -27). I am able to hear the data initially but when other transaction begins on HID report endpoint, alsa crashes with the mentioned error.

I am working on imx6q board with linux kernel-3.0.35. I am using Apple device to get the digital audio.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the host controller driver.

Comment: I am using EHCI HCD. Is there any way out to solve this issue ??